# What do the numbers by the tags on the Recent Tags sidebar mean?

Tags: support, sidebar, recent-tags

When you have Hot Network Questions disabled on your profile, the Recent Tags and Recent Badges sidebars appear. In the Recent Tags sidebar, there are numbers next to all the tags, like this:

> [image: [bug] × 324]

What do those numbers mean? I'm guessing that they're the number of questions tagged with that tag recently, but *how* recently?